# Is KafkaConsumer listTopics() method threadsafe?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I locally tested it and found out that though poll can't be called from multiple threads, listTopics() and metrics() methods work. does that mean that calling these methods is ok from multiple threads. Want to confirm with experts here to avoid any issues in production

Answer (score 0):

These are the methods of Kafka Consumer which works as a client that consumes records from Kafka Cluster.
**The consumer is not thread-safe**. The consumer maintains TCP connections to the necessary brokers to fetch data.

**Multi-threaded Processing**

The Kafka consumer is NOT thread-safe. All network I/O happens in the thread of the application
making the call.

It is the responsibility of the user to ensure that multi-threaded access
 is properly synchronized. Un-synchronized access will result in [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).

So **listTopics() and metrics()** methods are not thread-safe. You can go through the Kafka source code to get more details.

https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/master/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.java

Comment: I have tried locally and tried calling .metrics() from more than 4 threads and it all worked. Same happened with listTopics() as well.

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#multithreaded is not thread-safe. Even Testcases are also not covering this. Please raise your thoughts on the community with thread dump.